# "magento/module-new-relic-reporting" not installed after upgrade

Tags: magento, compiler-errors, compilation, magento2, newrelic

So, I did a lot of research and tried a lot of ideas to solve this but without luck. That's why I'm asking.

I'm trying to upgrade magento from 2.3.3 to 2.4.4 . I stacked on a problem that "magento/module-new-relic-reporting" is not installed by composer and causing problem during setup:di:complie :

```
Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #0 [ <required> Magento\NewRelicReporting\Model\Config $config ] of Magento\GraphQl\Model\Query\Logger\NewRelic class 



Class "Magento\NewRelicReporting\Model\Config" does not exist
```

Please give me some clues ...

Comment: i'm shooting in the dark here, but maybe you had a patch applied on version 2.3.3 on the module and this patch is not valid for the new version of the module.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2.4.4 has 100.4.2 version of magento/module-new-relic-reporting.
Check your version first.